# Converting the standard deviation of an averaged score to the standard deviation of a total score

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I need to obtain the standard deviation of a total score on a 3-item scale that has been tested on a non-clinical population. The total score is calculated by summing scores for the three questions that make up the scale. Each of these questions is a 0-10 score. The average total scale score can be expressed either as a total score/30 or as an average item score/10.

My problem is that the study that tested this scale on a non-clinical population has reported the average item score (/10) not the summed score (/30). They tested it on *n*=1081 participants and report an average item score (/10) of 4.6 with a sd of 8.1 (which I calculated myself as they reported the standard error, which was 0.061, so sd = se x sqrt(n) = 0.061 x sqrt(1081) = 8.1).

Now extrapolating the average item score (/10) to a total score (/30) is easy, just multiply by 3, so 3 x 4.6 = 13.8/30. But **how do I perform a similar extrapolation on the standard deviation of the average item score?**. How do I reverse-engineer the standard deviation of an averaged score to convert it to the standard deviation of a total score?

Pretty sure it's not possible with the info I have, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Sd(aX) =a*sd(X). Just multiply the sd by 3.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse @jsk. So m(sd) for average item score = 4.6 (8.1) becomes m (sd) for total score = 13.8 (24.3)? Is it really that simple?

Comment: Yeah, it's that simple. It's a nice property of standard deviations.